# Connecting mother board, power supply, and tower

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan

I am working on putting together a desktop for the first time and and ran into a problem, I am not sure how to connect the fans that came in my tower, my power supply, and connect them all to the mother board.

1. [Tower](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811119197)
2. [Mobo](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131979&cm_re=asus_z87_pro-_-13-131-979-_-Product)
3. [Power Supply](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817139040&cm_re=cx_750-_-17-139-040-_-Product)

There are 3 fans in the tower, each have 3 pin male and female connector that come connected, and 4 pin (larger?) male and female connector which are hanging. How would I go about connecting The fans together then to the power supply and mobo so it is easiest control (or suggest me a smart / better option).

Pictures are from fans on HAF 922 Tower.

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: @Psycogeek So you're saying I connect each fan directly to the motherboard to be able to control the fans via asus software? Which pins do I use, the 1x4 male, 1x4 female, or 1x3 pin male?

Answer (score 1):

The power supply has a 12x2 pin alignment.  This goes to the MoBo with the 12x2 female pins alignment.  the 1x4 large encased pins connected to the fan goes into the power supply's 1x4 on the bottom picture described.
This power supply has a bunch of these 1x4 enclosed female pins.  The power supply can also house 1x3 connectors, to directly connect the fan to power supply without having to have a need to a converter, such as the one your holding in the bottom picture.  When I looked at your power supply via the link given, you can connect maybe 3 of those fan that have 1x3 connectors.

To better connect these fan from the case, you need to connect them to the MoBo itself, but because you do not have the proper MoBo for these fan to directly connect into, your best bet is an internal fan controller.  Otherwise, you could zip tie it all, so it does get in the way.

If all else fails, read the manual given to you.

Comment: I connected the power supply 12x2 pins together. So you're saying each fan will connect directly to the power supply, and not to each other? Do I only connect each fan (male) to the power supply (female) once? Also, what is an internal fan controller, this? http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811992005 . Thanks for taking your time to help me. 

Edit: another user mentioned software control of the fans through asus, which I **do** want. How do I do that?

Comment: Yes they will connect to the power supply 1x4 pins once.  male to female.  That is one is what I was talking about, yes.  I am not exactly sure.  I haven't played with ASUS MoBo control for about 5 years.

Comment: My motherboard supports 4 1x4 pin fan headers, will the 1x3 pin connectors work with them as well? http://pcdiy.asus.com/2013/07/z87-pro-comprehensive-feature-overview/

Comment: no thats what @Pyscogeek was referring to adaptation.  You would need a 3 pin to 4 pin converter to just plug those in.

Comment: So these larger 1x4 pin connectors won't fit anything on the mobo? :/

Comment: no those aren't meant for mobo connection.  Just hardware like drives and the fans with the adapters you photographed.

Comment: I am reading about my motherboard and it says "The Z87-Pro features a total of six fan headers, each capable of supplying 1 ampere of current – more than enough for case-fans or other aftermarket solutions.

The other on-board fan headers regulate in DC mode only, so whether you’re using a 4-pin or 3-pin fan, it will be controlled in DC mode, allowing for speed control." Does this mean I can plug the fans into the mobo and control them with the software asus supplies with the mobo?

Comment: I am going to say real your manual and I will update my answer to relate to that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14972/discussion-between-virusboy-and-jordand).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achive asus software control of the fans in the case you do your best to connect them to the 4 chassis fan headers on the motherboard. Making sure that the fans do not go over the amperage max for the MB fan connectors. This is usually possible, though not always easy, or might require some adaption, or extention.

I far prefer this method, because with motherboard control, and the software you can get automated control of the fan based on a thermal profile.

Weird Stuff:
The 4 pin asus MB **chassis** fan (not cpu fan which is PWM) are more often not PWM controlled, but 4Pin, which can be confusing, because 4pin should mean PWM :-(. So a 3pin put in the correct alignment for the key slot thing, should work in the 4 pin slots, and fully control the speed. Check the manuel, and what people are saying about the PWM (or not) to verify. I only know about this from 4 boards so far.

It all is generally compatable:
So basically 3pin and 4pin Motherboard header pins are all compatable, and key in similarity.
 A real 4pin PWM fan put into a 3pin slot will be controlled only via changes in the power going to it, not via actual PWM pulses sent on the missing pwm line.
 A 3 Pin fan will Operate on a 4pin real PWM header also, but only at full speed.
Add in Asus having 4pin headers for chassis fans that are not real PWM controlled. It still all works. . . So a simple 3pin MB header type of connection , should still have full control, in the asus 4Pin Chassis fan locations.

The "Molex" (+5v Ground Ground +12V) connectors/adapters, the 4pin larger connections would be the connection used for connecting the fans to a PSU (with molex) Or to possible PSU "Fan-Only" type of connections (some PSUs). Or to connect to some seperate fan controllers. The ones shown are adapters with Passthrough capability, so you can connect something else with the Molex and still power the fan, or to chain more than one together from a single available molex connection.

Basic Idea put 12V on the fan in the correct polarity. (the 5V item on the same is left unconnected)

Also some cases have manuel control of fans, built into the case itself. It is more rare that case control of fans , is a full controller that also can create thermal profiles.  Cases have used both MB sized connections, and the big Molex connectors to connect to the controllers.  I do not see where the case you have chosen has that stuff.  So it kind of makes it easier, because you do not have to decide what method to use.

In the **Molex** (the big 4 pin plastic connectors)
Red is +5V
Black is common ground or 0V
Yellow is +12V

And the fans usually use +12v and the ground.

**On the Fan** wiring, they are more often using
Red for the +voltage (yea which is 12v)
Black for the common ground 0V
Yellow for the RPM line back to the MB.

You can see easily what is going on, with these Molex fan adapters, with the yellow +12Volt line headed to the Red +12V line of the fan.
This changing the colors is why it is very usefull to read the manuels, and/or have a voltmeter to verify things.

Comment: So I can connect the 3 pin fan connectors directly to my mobo and have them constantly running at maximum speed? I may do that to start since I don't know if I understand the rest of your directions.

Comment: I am reading about my motherboard and it says "The Z87-Pro features a total of six fan headers, each capable of supplying 1 ampere of current – more than enough for case-fans or other aftermarket solutions.

The other on-board fan headers regulate in DC mode only, so whether you’re using a 4-pin or 3-pin fan, it will be controlled in DC mode, allowing for speed control." Does this mean I can plug the fans into the mobo and control them with the software asus supplies with the mobo?

Comment: The general concept is if it has 3 holes, it requires three pins to do that what it was intended to do.

Comment: @JordanD yes it does. the 2 CPU fan connection points are the only real PWM and would prefer to have a real 4Pin PWM fan. The chassis fans will be controlled with the 3 pins connected.